# Comparing overdispersion distributions

Tags: references, count-data, overdispersion

I am dealing with handling overdispersed count data (Poisson distributions fails to fit).

I need to compare three different mixtures (Gamma, Log-Normal and Inverse Gaussian) of Poisson rate parameter distributions using a simulation study.

I would like to know the available methods (apart from Likelihood ratio and Pearson's Chi Square test) to compare three completely different distributions to fit overdispersed count data.

Any reference also highly appreciated!!

Comment: Why wouldn't you also consider a negative binomial model?

Comment: As  for Michael's comment, note that Poisson with parameter gamma distributed __is__ the negative binomial model ....  It could be easier, speaking of programming, to use the negative binomial directly.

Comment: You could trey a qqplot against the three distributions